# Traefik is getting "404 Page not found" in AWS

Tags: kubernetes, ingress

I installed my Traefik with default files from: https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#configuration-examples

My ingressroute is looking like that:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: traefik-test-ingressroute
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - traefik
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`test.domain.com`) 
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 80
```

In dashboard rule is looks correctly. Its finding all endpoints and is signed as "Success". But when i put domain "test.domain.com" to my browser it is getting me 404. I using this domain with ip of AWS loadbalancer created by Traefik service in my /etc/hosts.

Traffik is reaching Traefik because in logs im getting such log on every connection try:

```
172.20.59.64 - - [29/Mar/2020:22:19:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 190 "-" "-" 0ms
172.20.59.64 - - [29/Mar/2020:22:19:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 191 "-" "-" 0ms
172.20.59.64 - - [29/Mar/2020:22:19:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 192 "-" "-" 0ms
172.20.59.64 - - [29/Mar/2020:22:19:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 193 "-" "-" 0ms
172.20.59.64 - - [29/Mar/2020:22:19:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 194 "-" "-" 0ms
172.20.59.64 - - [29/Mar/2020:22:21:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 195 "-" "-" 0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved issue. Problem was with my configuration. We are not putting traefik service in to endpoint but name of endpoint configured in traefik arguments like:

```
--entryPoints.web.address=:80
```

so config should looks like:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: traefik-test-ingressroute
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - web
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`test.domain.com`) 
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 80
```